# Why a plugin function is NOT defined but js reference is being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm using a third party modal plugin: wModal.js from [Websanova.com](http://Websanova.com)

My javascript libraries are all loading at the bottom of my document. That's fine.

Here's the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wModal/wModal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simplyCountable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hoverfold.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wysiwyg.image.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wysiwyg.link.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wysiwyg.table.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.69142.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var elapsedTime = 0;
    var sessTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
    sessTimeout = parseFloat(sessTimeout);
    // set to the Session.Timeout value to notify users
    // one minute after their Session times out.
    var maxTime = (sessTimeout + 1) * 60;
    var oneSecond;
    oneSecond = window.setTimeout("timeoutCheck();", 1000);
    var today = new Date();



    //Set the Copyright Date
    window.onload = function () {

        var myDate = today.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getFullYear();
        $("#cDate").html(today.getFullYear());

        var ftoday;
        ftoday = new Date();
        var myFDate = ftoday.getFullYear() + "." + (ftoday.getMonth() + 1) + "." + ftoday.getDate();
        $("#fCdate").html(ftoday.getFullYear());
        $("#fBdate").html(myFDate);
        $("#bYr").html(ftoday.getYear() + "." + ftoday.getDate());

    };



    $(document).ready(function () {

        //dynamically load Modals 
        $.get('includes/help-modal.html', function (data) {
            //Load the DIV with all the modals
            $('#templates').html(data);



            $('#wModal_info').wModal({
                position: 'cm', //This means: Center Middle
                offset: '5',
                fxShow: 'slideDown',
                fxHide: 'slideUp',
                btns: {
                    'ok': function () {
                        console.log('original info');
                        this.hide();
                        //...some other function can be called here
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        //This fires the MODAL HELP window
        $("#btnHelp").click(function () {
            $("#wModal_info").wModal('show'); <--THIS IS THE PROBLEM
        });
    });

    function timeoutCheck() {
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime + 1;
        if (elapsedTime > maxTime) {
            window.location = "youTimedOut.asp";
        }
        else {
            oneSecond;
        }
    }
    //This fakes a window so you can close a tab in the browser
    function tricky_win_close() {
        window.open('', '_self', '');
        window.close();
    }

    //Check where we are...
    var pageName = "<%= Session("current_page") %>"; //Don't worry, this works...not the problem
            if (pageName === "login") {

        $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
            $("#username").val(function (i, val) {
                if (val === "") {
                    $('#warning').html("<font=red class=compname>Username Missing</font>");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $("#password").val(function (i, val) {
                if (val === "") {
                    $('#warning').html("<font=red class=compname>Username Missing</font>");
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $("form1").submit();
        });
        $("#username").on("change", function () {
            $(this).val(function (i, val) {
                if (val !== "") {
                    $('#warning').html("");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
        $("#password").on("change", function () {
            $(this).val(function (i, val) {
                if (val !== "") {
                    $('#warning').html("");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

So when I click on btnHelp in the browser, the call to OPEN the wModal dialog fails with:

Uncaught Typeerror: undefined is NOT a function.

Actually, it IS and there are NO errors loading the page only and until I click the "btnHelp" button.

I'm confused. I've used this before...wModal.js that is.  Here:
 https://github.com/websanova/wModal#wmodaljs

I've put the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` but to no avail... I've taken it out...

The instantiation event "lives" inside the `$.get('includes/help-modal.html', function (data) {....`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:  So here's a screen shot of my DEV CONSOLE in CHROME.

[image: This is the Dev Console showing the error "AFTER" I click the btnHelp]

Hope this helps, because I don't see how it's NOT being defined.

Thanks again

Comment: Maybe you're clicking the button before the AJAX request has returned and the modal has been instantiated? Or maybe that request fails, and the modal is never instantiated at all?

Comment: Yeah, but when I'm in Chrome's debugger, the wModal.js library is there and the click event STOPS at the breakpoint when I click on the button.  I step into the function above (the btnHelp click) and it hits the wModal show function. As I step OUT, the error occurs.

Comment: Trim this down to a self-contained example; you may end up finding the problem just in doing that.